# How to change ANTD table text to different language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, antd

I want the ant design (React) pagination to be in my language (spanish). The ideal thing would be to render "por página" instead of "page" in the next picture:

(code)

```
 pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 3, showSizeChanger: true, pageSizeOptions: ['5','10', '20', '30']}}
```

(picture)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: mmmm not exactly, my goal is to personalize the text, but thanks man

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Explanation

This is often so called `i18n` or `internationalization`

And Ant does have an Internationalization solution provided.

Refer to document [ant i18n](https://ant.design/docs/react/i18n), you can find the language list there.

---

#### Demo

- for example: In spanish

[image]

---

#### Usage

```
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import es_ES from 'antd/es/locale/es_ES';

return (
  <ConfigProvider locale={es_ES}>
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>
);
```

Try it online:

[image: Edit cold-resonance-ebmiv]

Comment: is there a way to detect the locale of the user browser in antd?